# Why doesn't textView21.SetLeftTopRightBottom(1,200,45, 275) change the size of a textview?

Tags: layout, xamarin.android, textview

Why doesn't textView21.SetLeftTopRightBottom(1,200,45, 275) change the size of a textview?

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView21_id"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_x="22dp"
    android:layout_y="105dp"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#9999cc"
    android:singleLine="false"/>
```

There's the activity_main.xml snippet. Is there something there which overrides the SetLeftTopRightBottom?

I am still trying to get two different but ordinary mobile phones (cell phones) to display a view the same.
[pic of same app in two phones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrdgz.jpg)

You can see the left hand pic shows to below the grey '6:' textview and includes the 'Go' textview and all the right hand 5th-letter-in-the-word textview areas whereas the other pic doesn't.

I've figured out how to get each phone's display metrics

```
        var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        gnumWidthDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.WidthPixels);
        gnumHeightDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.HeightPixels);
```

I thought it would be easy to do the SetLeftTopRightBottom thing and set each textview in the right place.

Please can you tell me what I have missed? Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

In the official document, SetLeftTopRightBottom method is meant to be used in animations only as it applies this position and size for the view only temporary and it can be changed back at any time by the layout.

More information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setLeftTopRightBottom(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

In addition, the size of the textview21 had been ensured in the xml. If you want to set the size of it dynamically, you need to use the LayoutParams. Such as:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 200);
//300 is width and 200 is height
textView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
```